# Filter Certain Lines In Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, lines

I am trying to use Javascript to filter certain lines from an input I have this input:

```
Interface name : Wi-Fi 5
There are 15 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : 9bf6fe
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP

SSID 2 : melitaWIFI
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : Open
    Encryption              : None
```

How can I use JS to filer only every fifth line in this case?

Comment: Please include the code for what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

If your input is stored in a variable:

```
var input = "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\nk\nl";

var lines = input.split("\n");
for (i = 4; i < lines.length; i += 5) {
    console.log(lines[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting every 5th line**

First of all, you can get an array of lines by using the `split()` method:

```
var lines = input.split("\n");
```

Then you can loop through this array and for every 5th item you can add the line to a new array:

```
var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    var line = lines[i];  
    if((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
        results.push(line);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tC5rW/)

**Getting values for a specific key**

If you wanted to get values for say `"Network type"`, you could create a function to find all watching key values:

```
function getValuesForKey(lines, key) {
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        var pairs = line.split(":");
        if (pairs.length == 2 && pairs[0].trim() == key) {
            results.push(pairs[1].trim());
        }
    }

    return results;
}

var lines = input.split("\n");
var results = getValuesForKey(lines, "Network type");
console.log(results);
```

[Here is an example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/tC5rW/1/)